# bindParam gives Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, prepared-statement

im trying prepared statements to send data to my table. but it is giving me error. am  i doing this wrong? what did i do wrong here?

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound
>   variables does not match number of tokens

my code is below

```
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mystic_male (id, Name, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9, Time)
    VALUES (:id, :Name, :M1, :M2, :M3, :M4, :M5, :M6, :M7, :M8, :M9, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $Name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':M1', $M1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':M1', $M2);
    $stmt->bindParam(':M1', $M3);
    $stmt->bindParam(':M1', $M4);
    $stmt->bindParam(':M1', $M5);
    $stmt->bindParam(':M1', $M6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':M1', $M7);
    $stmt->bindParam(':M1', $M8);
    $stmt->bindParam(':M1', $M9);


    // insert a row
    $id = "";
    $Name = "$ps0";
    $M1 =  "$ps1";
    $M2 =  "$ps2";
    $M3 =  "$ps3";
    $M4 =  "$ps4";
    $M5 =  "$ps5";
    $M6 =  "$ps6";
    $M7 =  "$ps7";
    $M8 =  "$ps8";
    $M9 =  "$ps9";

    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You're binding `:M1` but you have them up to `:M9`. Did you not read your code?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `$stmt->bindParam(':M2', $M2);` and so on?

Comment: @Mjh thanks :3 again. i feel stupid now

Comment: where is binding varaibles